# Skip view from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate

I have a problem with my iOS application. once a user islogged on I want to led him directly to my MainViewController instead of the LoginViewController.

[image]

When I do this in the following way, I get an empty view in my simulator.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    NSString *storyboardId = nil;

    if(success){
        storyboardId = @"MainView";
    } else {
        storyboardId = @"LoginView";
    }

    UIViewController *controller = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `storyboardId` are the same you defined on your Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, where te image says "PageViewController" I have "MainView" http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/page-view-controller-5.jpeg my views are both of a different custom class, is that a problem?

Comment: And it works fine if the `success` value is **NO**?

Comment: I tried both, my login view will shown up but the main view wil only be activated after the login segue that is fired from the login button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you alloc/init self.window, its rootViewController property will be nil.  Hence your `instantiateViewController` method is being sent to nil.  Hence it returns nil.  And so you then set rootViewController to nil.  You could use storyboardWithName:bundle: to get a valid storyboard for the instantiateViewController method.  But how will you determine `success` from within your App Delegate?  Why not just present your login viewController modally from within the mainViewController?

Comment: I set success earlier in my AppDelegate based upon a web service which starts a session.
What is the best way to present my view within a view modally?

Comment: In viewDidLoad of your MainViewController, alloc/init an instance of your LoginViewController, and then use the ` presentViewController:animated:completion:` method to display the login.  Once your user is logged in, use `dismissViewController:animated:completion:` to go back to your MainViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    NSString *storyboardId = nil;

    if(success){
        storyboardId = @"MainView";
    } else {
        storyboardId = @"LoginView";
    }
    UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_name" bundle: nil];

    UIViewController *controller = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

At the storyboard name you have to put your storyboard's name. The point that I guess you are being wrong is at self.window.rootViewController.storyboard which I think is empty, because self.window was just allocated.

Comment: I have tried this but this also does not give the desired result.

Comment: You must be wrong at some point, because I am using this method and it works. When you define the class of viewController, be sure that your storyboardID is Storyboard ID and not custom class. Also be sure that you have a correct name for your Storyboard. Anyway, clean the data and run the project again, cmd+shift+k

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is a combination of the responses of [Erid Bardhaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2664437/erid-bardhaj/) and [jMelnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842715/jmelnik/)

I embed my loginViewController into a Navigation Controller

[image]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;

    if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle: nil];
        NSLog(@"I am an iPad");
    } else {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
        NSLog(@"I am an iPhone");
    }

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Username"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Password"];
    NSString *deviceID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceID"];

    if(deviceID == nil){
        deviceID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
        [defaults setObject:deviceID forKey:@"DeviceID"];
    }

    NSLog(@"DeviceID: %@",deviceID);


    if((username == (id)[NSNull null] || username.length == 0 ) || (password == (id)[NSNull null] || password.length == 0 )) {
        LoginViewController *loginViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;

    } else {
        SWRevealViewController  *mainViewController= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
    }
    [defaults synchronize];

    return YES;
}
```